# Birkat haMazon (Grace after Meals) during Sukkot outside the sukkah

Tags: halacha, sukkah, sukkot, bentching

Since during Sukkot holiday one can have a meal with bread only in sukkah (i.e., only the sukkah space could be the one that will require you to say birkat hamazon, to be kovea seudah), if one ate in the sukkah, can he say birkat hamazon outside of the sukkah (possibly, there is a problem with shinuy a-makom and kviyut ha-seudah). What do you say?

Comment: Why would he want to? You live in the sukkah

Comment: @DoubleAA There are plenty of cases where one would change location. Let's say it started BEFORE he started bentsching. or something else called him away. The halachah addresses the requirement to eat in the sukkah but not the bracha achronah - you don't need to sit to say an al hamichyah, for instance, which could be said standing outside the sukkah

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I didn't say why would it possibly happen. I said why would he want to? If you end up outside your house you also bentch there, but why would you want that? The Halacha is you live in your sukkah.

Comment: In regular setting you are obligated to say Birkat HaMazon in the place you are kovea your seuda - or, could possibly be kovea. But what about the places you can't be kovea seudah? Can you say Birkat haMazon in those places?

Comment: @DoubleAA That may be true, but the question is asking about whether it is possible to do so. The reasons seem to be irrelevant here.

Comment: @Avraham'sLight Not really clear on what you're asking, but you might want to post it as a separate question, perhaps with a link back here...

Comment: I am asking whether the parameters of the physical space play any role in the definition of the "makom seudah", or, rather, it is totally mental category that is dependent only on one's intention? It looks like, at least, according to Bais Shammay, one won't be allowed to bentch outside of the sukkah. What would Bais Hillel say?